# Killing all iexplore processes after test run fails

Tags: coded-ui-tests, specflow, mtm

When we run our CodedUI tests and the test cases fail we kill the Internet Explorer process by calling `Kill()` below:

```
private static readonly HashSet<string> ProcessesToKill = 
    new HashSet<string>(new[] { "iexplore" });

public static void Kill()
{
    var runningProcessesToKill = (from p in Process.GetProcesses()
        where ProcessesToKill.Contains(p.ProcessName, 
            StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
        select p).ToArray();

    // First try to close the process in a friendly way
    CloseProcess(runningProcessesToKill);

    // Then wait for a while to give the processes time to terminate
    WaitForProcess(runningProcessesToKill);

    // If not closed kill the process.
    KillProcess(runningProcessesToKill);
}
```

Killing is done by calling `CloseMainWindow()` and `Close()` on the processes first, then waiting for a while and then calling `Kill()` on the processes.

Unfortunately, this does not close a JavaScript alert popup. When the test run is finished this remains in the screen blocking the next test, like so:

[image: Popup remains in screen]

Why does it not close the alert, and how can we fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can brute force this using the `taskkill` command from the command line:

```
C:\>taskkill /F /IM iexplore.exe
```

This, of course, doesn't help you with your tests. Instead, use `Process.Start(...)`:

```
public static void Kill()
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("taskkill", "/F /IM iexplore.exe");
}
```

This will shut down all Internet Explorer processes, regardless of whether or not they have an alert or confirm dialog visible.

References:

- [How Do I Kill All the iexplore.exe Processes at Once?](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/how-do-i-kill-all-the-iexploreexe-processes-at-once/)
- [Run Command Prompt Commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469764/run-command-prompt-commands)